# How to update datagrid sort when adding items (using MVVM and no code-behind)

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a datagrid that correctly sorts when initially loaded. But it doesn't update when I add an item. How can I have the grid update and sort when a new item is added?

```
<!-- This works for the initial sort, but when members get added to the collection
     the sort doesn't get updated. That's because CollectionViewSource doesn't 
     implement INotifyPropertyChanged. -->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedApplications" Source="{Binding Applications}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Name" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

One option is to sort the collection within the view model. But if I'm displaying all of the Bars within a Foo, I would then have to break Bars into its own property (in the view model) just so I could sort them.

If possible, I would like to do this without using the view's code-behind because I'm trying not to put code there.

Comment: What type of collection is Applications?

Comment: public ObservableCollection<Application> Applications

Answer (score 0):

By default the DataGrid supports sorting without having to specify a SortDescription. In fact, I think the problem you're seeing is that your SortDescription is overriding the DataGrid's sorting. I'd recommend one of two things:

1. Removing the SortDescription and letting the DataGrid handle the sorting
2. Move the CollectionViewSource to the ViewModel and add a Sorting handler to the DataGrid which calls into the ViewModel and manages the SortDescriptions.

If you plan on managing the SortDescriptions yourself remember to clear the SortDescriptions collection before adding a new one so that the sort order is correct.

**Update:**

If your DataGrid isn't updating when a new item is added to the collection that it's bound to then your collection isn't raising the CollectionChanged event. Make sure you're binding to something the implements INofityCollectionChanged - like an ObservableCollection.

**Update:** 
Here's an example that inserts items in sorted order. How does your code differ?

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase" Title="MainWindow">
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="SortedApplications" Source="{Binding Items}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="Age" Direction="Ascending"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <Button Content="Add Item" Click="AddItem_"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SortedApplications}}"/>
</StackPanel>       
</Window>
```

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Items { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = this;
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
        Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Foo", Age = 1 });
        Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Bar", Age = 3 });
        Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Foo", Age = 31 });
        Items.Add(new Person { Name = "Bar", Age = 42 });
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void AddItem_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Add(new Person { Name = "test", Age = DateTime.Now.Second});
    }
}


public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: There are several, but the easiest might be to Bind your DataGrid's ItemsSource directly to the Applications collection in your ViewModel

Comment: And how does the sorting happen in that case? Does the view model handle the sorting then?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Where are you specifying which property to use as the sort?

Comment: By default, the DataGrid sorts by the first column (the first property on the object). Clicking a column header will change which column the DataGrid sorts by.

Comment: It just hit me that we may not be on the same page here. I don't want the user to have to click a header to sort. The DataGrid doesn't sort on its own; it displays data as it exists in the view model binding. I simply want a grid to be sorted by a certain column, and stay sorted even when adding/removing items.